# Inconsistent KeyEvent Consumption by TextField

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TextField` and a `TableView` in a `BorderPane`.

I wanted to assign program-wide hotkey to the program for the key `s`, so I put a `EventListener <KeyEvent>` on the `BorderPane`.

This seemed to work perfectly -- events pressed on the table were passed through to the `BorderPane` but events in the `TextField` that created text were consumed before getting to my listener.

I then wanted to add a similar hotkey for `Shift + s`. In this case, the `TextField` does not consume the KeyEvent, so it types the letter `S` (capital) into the `TextField` but also passes the key event to my BorderPane rather than consuming the event.

Here is a runnable example:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class KeyEventIssue extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws Exception {

        TextField textInput = new TextField();
        TableView <Locale> table = getFilledTable();

        BorderPane primaryContainer = new BorderPane();

        primaryContainer.setTop( textInput );
        primaryContainer.setCenter( table );

        primaryContainer.setOnKeyPressed( ( KeyEvent e ) -> { 
            if ( e.getCode() == KeyCode.S 
            && !e.isControlDown() && !e.isAltDown() && !e.isShiftDown() && !e.isMetaDown() ) {
                System.out.println ( "Heard s" );
                e.consume();
            } else if ( e.getCode() == KeyCode.S && e.isShiftDown() 
            && !e.isControlDown() && !e.isAltDown() && !e.isMetaDown() ) {
                System.out.println ( "Heard Shift + s" );
                e.consume();
            } 
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene( primaryContainer );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.setWidth( 700 );
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView <Locale> getFilledTable () {
        TableView <Locale> table = new TableView <>( FXCollections.observableArrayList( Locale.getAvailableLocales() ) );
        TableColumn <Locale, String> countryCode = new TableColumn <>( "CountryCode" );
        countryCode.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <>( "country" ) );
        TableColumn <Locale, String> language = new TableColumn <>( "Language" );
        language.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <>( "language" ) );

        TableColumn <Locale, Locale> local = new TableColumn <>( "Locale" );
        local.setCellValueFactory( c -> new SimpleObjectProperty <>( c.getValue() ) );

        language.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <>( "language" ) );

        table.setColumnResizePolicy( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );

        table.getColumns().addAll( countryCode, language, local );

        return table;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Application.launch ( args );
    }
}
```

Actions for you to take to reproduce the issue:

1. Compile and run this program
2. Press `s` while Tableview has focus -- "Heard s" is printed -- **good**
3. Press `s` while TextField has focus -- nothing is printed and the `s` is put in the text box -- **good**
4. Press `shift + s` while Tableview has focus -- "Heard Shift + s" is printed -- **good**
5. Press `shift + s` while TextField has focus -- "Heard Shift + s" is printed and `S` is put in the text box -- **BAD** -- nothing should print.

This appears to me to be inconsistent behavior. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in javafx?

I can do a workaround by checking whether the text box has focus, and I'll probably do that for my project, but it has a handful of textboxes, and more may be added in the future. I am hoping to avoid having to do that because it will lead to harder-to-maintain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a bug report. This is a known issue in Java 8, fixed in Java 9 according to the Java developers: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194280